# Android reading JSONArray from JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am trying to read from json file, the file have JSONArray inside JSONObject, it is reading the first JSONObject value but not reading from inside inside array called "zoom", can you please help me?

```
    {
   "@file_name": "materials",
   "materials": [
        {
            "@site_name": "N/A",
            "@site_icon_iPad_xPosition": "150",
            "@site_icon_iPad_yPosition": "150",
            "@site_icon_Android_xPosition": "215",
            "@site_icon_Android_yPosition": "206",
            "zoom": 
                {
                    "@zoom_name": "Main Reservoir",
                    "@zoom_number": "zoom1"

                }

        },
        {
            "@site_name": "Building Applications",
            "@site_icon_iPad_xPosition": "636",
            "@site_icon_iPad_yPosition": "313",
            "@site_icon_Android_xPosition": "215",
            "@site_icon_Android_yPosition": "206",
            "zoom": [
                {
                    "@zoom_name": "Rooftop Reservoir &amp; Pump Station",
                    "@zoom_number": "zoom10-1"

                },
                {
                    "@zoom_name": "Compact Zone PRV System",
                    "@zoom_number": "zoom10-2"

                },
                {
                    "@zoom_name": "Basement Reservoir &amp; Pump Room",
                    "@zoom_number": "zoom10-3"

                }
            ]           
        }
   ]
}
```

My code:

```
 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
         JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Materials.json");

            try {


                JSONArray materials = json.getJSONArray("materials");
                for(int i = 0; i < materials.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject c = materials.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String a1= c.getString("@site_name");
                    String a2 = c.getString("@site_icon_Android_xPosition");
                    String a3 = c.getString("@site_icon_Android_yPosition");

                    Log.d(TAG, a1+" "+a2+" "+a3);


                    JSONArray zoom = c.getJSONArray("zoom");
                    Log.d(TAG, ""+zoom.length());
                    for(int j = 0; j < zoom.length(); j++){

                        JSONObject d = zoom.getJSONObject(j);
                         String b1 = d.getString("@zoom_name");
                         String b2 = d.getString("@zoom_number");
                         Log.d(TAG, b1+" "+b2);
                    }

                   Log.d(TAG, "--------------------------------");


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "exeption");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My output:

```
Applications 215 206
exeption
```

Exception:

```
03-24 11:29:01.188: W/System.err(17952): org.json.JSONException: Value {"@zoom_number":"zoom1","@zoom_name":"Main Reservoir"} at zoom of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at com.weterworks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:120)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-24 11:29:01.198: W/System.err(17952):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small error in your code. In your inner loop that processes the `zoom` property, you are referring to the wrong array object.

```
for (int j = 0; j < zoom.length(); j++) {

    JSONObject d = materials.getJSONObject(j); // <-- Should refer to zoom, not materials
    String b1 = d.getString("@zoom_name");
    String b2 = d.getString("@zoom_number");
    Log.d(TAG, b1 + " " + b2);
}
```

Comment: Thanx, I changed materials.getJSONObject(j) to zoom.getJSONObject(j) still this not working, I getting the same error.

Comment: Whats the exception stack trace? Add it to your question.

Comment: just tested this solution fixed the problem

Comment: @Mr.Me - yes, I ran it with the JSON fragment the OP included and it works for me as well. Kudos for testing.

Comment: @user1891408 - I know that you modified your JSON before posting it as an example (I had to clean it up to get it too run). Which isn't a problem, but, it looks from your exception like you may be mapping the wrong attribute as an array. You may want to include a representation of the your full JSON in the question.

Comment: I have changed the error code in my question. And also changed the json file as it the question. I`m sorry Mr.Me, but you did not tested it, in my original question there were some commas that returned error.